# Monaco Editor intellisense from multiple files

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using monaco-editor and I would like to include suggestions from multiple files. I am not sure what is the best way to do it but basically, I want that when I am exporting some functions in a file2.js, to be able to access that from another file1.js in the suggestions.

Any idea on how to achieve that ?
Thank you !

file1

```js
var express = require('express');
var pug = require('pug');
var config = require('./config');
var fs = require('fs');
var router = express.Router();
var utils = require('/utils');
// Here I would like to use the function newTest from the other file 
but it does not show in the suggestions
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("ip - ", req.connection.remoteAddress)
    res.send(pug.compileFile('views/main.pug')({
        config
    }))
});
module.exports = router;
```

file2

```js
function newTest() {
    
}
module.exports.newTest = newTest;
```

editorFile

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// I prefetch my models, then I have a callback to create an instance of the editor
preFetchAllModels(function() {
    var models = monaco.editor.getModels();
    // I check that I have my models (file1 and file2) prefetched before creating the editor
    console.log("models", models);
    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setEagerModelSync(true)

    monacoEditor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("editor"), {
        value: "loading...",
        language: "javascript",
        theme: 'monokai',
        lineHeight: 20,
        fontSize: 16,
        wordWrap: "bounded",
        automaticLayout: true,
        wrappingIndent: 'indent'
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation ? https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/index.html

Comment: Yes, I spent a lot of time trying to find that in the documentation but without any success

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  You question could be improved by providing a specific example for what you have tried so far and what are the outcomes of those efforts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following code did the trick:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
        allowNonTsExtensions: true
});
```

Answer (score 13):

To achieve the goal of IntelliSense across multiple files, you need to use a single instance of `monaco.editor` and for each file you want IntelliSense for, initialize a new model, during application boot.  Additionally, for autocompletion support,
you must implement a completion item provider.  Read below for more details.

### Application Initial Load

1. Use `const myEditorInstance = monaco.editor.create({ ... , model: null })` to create a **single** editor instance.
2. Create n-model instances via `monaco.editor.createModel(...)` where `n` is the number of files.
3. Configure language defaults for [eager model sync](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.languageservicedefaults.html#seteagermodelsync): `monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setEagerModelSync(true)`.
4. To enable autocompletion, you will need to implement a method according to the [CompletionItemProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitemprovider.html) api.

### Handling various events after initial load

- Get a list of existing models via `monaco.editor.getModels()`.
- When a file is opened (either by a user clicking on a button or programmatically by some code you write), set the editor instance's model to the file you want to open using `myEditorInstance.setModel(model)`.
- When closing a file, you should save that model's view state (includes cursor position, etc) using `myEditorInstance.saveViewState()`.
- If opening that file again, you may restore that previous model state using `myEditorInstance.restoreState()`.
- If a file is renamed or deleted, you need to properly dispose the corresponding model and in the case where the file was renamed, re-initialize the model.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I did create n-model instances before creating the editor instance as you said. Then I also configured the setEagerModelSync. So far I did not enabled auto-completion because I am not so sure of how to do so. However, should I be able to see the suggestions (without enabling auto-completion) ? Because I don't see functions coming from other files.. Maybe it can be linked to the URI ? (does the uri have to serve the file, or it's not used except as an id ? ) Thanks for your help !

Comment: @BastienL. please edit your original question and add as much code as possible and try to incorporate the questions you have so we can better understand the problem and help you.

Comment: Better tutorial than official one, it's easier to understand how to build a monaco editor. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have almost the same use case as you, except I have one file I use as my "definitions" that populate the autocomplete for the main editor. Based on the answer provided by Peter I was able to put together the following working example. I believe the part that you are missing is creating the model and then using `editor.setModel(model)` to assign it to your editor.

```js
const editorOptions = {
    minimap: { enabled: false },
    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
    model: null,
    language: "javascript"
}

const initEditor = () => {
  monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setEagerModelSync(true)

  const defModel = monaco.editor.createModel(
    "const helloWorld = () => { return \"Hello World!\"; }",
    "javascript"
  )

  const textModel = monaco.editor.createModel(
    "helloWorld()",
    "javascript"
  )

  const e1 = monaco.editor.create(
    document.getElementById("editor1"), editorOptions
  )
  
  e1.setModel(defModel)
  
  const e2 = monaco.editor.create(
    document.getElementById("editor2"), editorOptions
  )
  
  e2.setModel(textModel)  
}

require.config({
    paths: {
        vs: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.18.0/min/vs"
    }
})

require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], initEditor)
```

```css
.editor {
  margin: 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.18.0/min/vs/loader.js"></script>

<h3>Definitions</h3>

<div class="editor" id="editor1" style="width: 100%; height: 40px"></div>

<h3>Editor</h3>

<div class="editor" id="editor2" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
```